# setting data in asp.net core auth middleware

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

I've got some OpenIdConnect auth middleware that needs to set some data so that further down in the middleware chain or in the controller I can access it. The usual way to do this is using `HttpContext.Items` so I'm doing this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
{
    // ...
    opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async ctx =>
        {
            // ... do some stuff ...
            ctx.HttpContext.Items["Something"] = somethingImportant;
        }
    };
});
```

But it's not working - when I example `HttpContext.Items` in my controller, it's empty. I've validated that it is being set by adding logging. Any ideas why, or there is an alternative to do this?

Comment: I don't have a solution right now, but I expect the `HttpContext` inside the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event is *different* to the one inside your controller, etc, because these are likely two different requests: 1. The request that retrieves the code itself and 2. Some sort of redirect that happens afterwards.

Comment: AH yes, I think you're probably right - I swapped to using session which is working for me so far